# Libgdx - how to load a huge spritesheet so it doesn't render black?

Tags: java, android, performance, libgdx, sprite-sheet

I'm facing a performance problem with my mobile game which I write in LibGDX.
Let's assume that there is only one resolution - `1920x1080` - just for testing.

I have a spritesheet combined with images like this below:
[image]

I want these particles to fly around my logo, so I need their size to be at least `256px/512px` - so it looks good on a given resolution.

If one frame has that size and I need at least 32 frames for it to look good, it's easy to calculate that the whole spritesheet has dimensions:

```
width: 256 * 8 (columns) = 2048
height: 512 * 4 (rows) = 2048
```

This is the most optimistic idea, cause the spritesheet should be even bigger.
The weight of the spritesheet is ~50kb so it's really fine, but the dimensions are getting me in trouble.

Yesterday I tested everything on a Desktop version in LibGDX, everything renders fine. I ported the game after finishing the menu to Android and the area where this spritesheet should be drawn is **black**.

I read on gamedev or here (don't remember) that I should use only graphics with a maximum size od `1024/1024` cause LibGdx has some problems with loading higher textures with Android on many versions.

What I'm trying to accomplish?
I need to find an idea how to make this work and load the texture.

I already tried with resizing the file using a pixmap, but it takes ints as dimensions, it lowers the quality etc...

I know someone would say, why wouldn't you just create a single 'dot' object with an orange graphic like below, spawn these dots randomly and change their alpha sometimes? It's not an option because I need other animations like 'fog' which can't be programmed that easy like dots.

Maybe there is a way to resize a texture, a region or something (using floats of course to keep the aspect ratio)?

If someone has any ideas, how should I use huge spritesheets in my app, I would be very grateful :)

Comment: If each individual texture is 256 x 512, couldn't you load 4 1024 x 1024 textures to work around the problem?

Comment: As I said, this is the most optimistic case, you know, a 256x512 piece on a 1920x1080 device looks really, really small. I need to downscale graphics, not upscale them! It should be even bigger so it doesn't lose quality when resizing :( When I have a bigger spritesheet, I would need to cut it in 20 smaller spritesheets, which does not make sense :(

Comment: For this particular animation, what about animating it directly in the game instead of trying to load a movie as textures? Or you could create an Android View that plays an actual mpeg movie before it loads your game.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by animating it directly in the game? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sprite sheet should not exceed the length 2048*2048.

If you want to load a spritesheet which is more than 2048*2048,then you have to load per frame separately.

Suppose, if your sprite sheet contains 15 frames then you must have 15 separate png files.

Comment: To be super clear - it should be 1024x1024 to be safe on all devices! :)